# No module named 'airflow.configuration' when running Airflow in Docker

Tags: python-3.x, docker, airflow, amazon-ecs

I have an AWS ECS Blue/Green deployment which runs a task with a docker container that has airflow 1.10.10.

When the task is runnin it shortly shows a running status but after that it dies.
If I get the logs from the docker I see:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 25, in <module>
    from airflow.configuration import conf
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'airflow.configuration'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 25, in <module>
Traceback (most recent call last):
    from airflow.configuration import conf
  File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 25, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'airflow.configuration'
    from airflow.configuration import conf
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'airflow.configuration'
```

I saw in other posts that the fix is to run:

```
pip install apache-airflow[crypto,postgres,ssh,s3]==1.10.10 \
    --constraint \
        https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/1.10.10/requirements/requirements-python3.7.txt
```

But it doesn't seem to work because I had the same error just before when run:

```
pip install apache-airflow[crypto,postgres,ssh,s3]==1.10.9
```

I don't know what happens here, because it happened suddenly without any change in docker or aws infrastructure.

Comment: Same error here, on fresh installation of Docker / Docker Compose on my Debian. Did you find a solution ?